# ValueError: X has 28 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 22 features as input

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm trying to figure out the importance of certain features in being able to predict the correct label.

I'm working on getting the linear regression of my data first but I'm getting errors during the prediction with the following error:

ValueError: X has 28 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 22 features as input.

I can't figure out why it's giving me that error. The column/rows in the test dataset are the same length as the training. I'm doing the same steps for train than for testing as far as I can tell.

What am I doing/assuming wrong?

Here is the code:

```
############ train

df_train = pd.read_excel('/content/feature importance training profiles.xlsx')

train_shuffled = df_train.sample(frac=1)

x_df_train = train_shuffled[['Name', 'middleName', 'lastnName', 'Certification', 'Location', 'College', 'Degree', 'Jobs', 'Company', 'Date', 'LocationJob']]

y_df_train = train_shuffled[['Label']]

############ test

df_test = pd.read_excel('/content/feature importance testing profiles.xlsx')

test_shuffled = df_test.sample(frac=1)

x_df_test = test_shuffled[['Name', 'middleName', 'lastnName', 'Certification', 'Location', 'College', 'Degree', 'Jobs', 'Company', 'Date', 'LocationJob', 'Label']]

#y_df_test = test_shuffled[['Label']]


#### encode train
skencoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')

#sk_data_train = skencoder.fit_transform(x_df_train[['Location', 'LocationJob']])

sk_data_train = skencoder.fit_transform(x_df_train[['LocationJob']])

#### encode test
skencoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')

#sk_data_test = skencoder.fit_transform(x_df_test[['Location', 'LocationJob']])

sk_data_test = skencoder.fit_transform(x_df_test[['LocationJob']])


# # define dataset
#X, y = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.33, random_state=25)

# enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder
# X_transform = enc.fit_transform(X)

model = LinearRegression().fit(sk_data_train, y_df_train)

print(model.predict(sk_data_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not include "Label" in x_df_test, because "Label" is what you will predict

```
x_df_test = test_shuffled[['Name', 'middleName', 'lastnName', 'Certification', 'Location', 'College', 'Degree', 'Jobs', 'Company', 'Date', 'LocationJob', 'Label']]
```

Remove "Label" from the list.